# iOS equivalent of Android´s BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In Android, you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` to be ran when the network is disconnected or reconnected -- even when the app is in suspended state.

What is the equivalent of that in iOS? I need to check for network changes even when the app gets into suspended state.

Comment: Have you checked out AFNetworking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Reachability Project  :

[Reachability network notifier](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)